# How to match any set of characters except a specific string in javascript regex ('==' for parsing Wikipedia section headers)

Tags: javascript, regex, wikipedia

For parsing headers of Wikipedia article sections I'd like to have a regex match anything except two or more equal signs ==.

For this I tried this regex: `([^==]+)` but it only checks for a single equal sign character (same as `([^=]+)`). Negative lookaheads also didn't work for this so far.

How can one use regex to match everything except of a specified string?

Comment: Are you looking for `(?:(?!==)[^])*`?

Comment: So if the header is "something something", that's OK, but if the header is "something==something" or "something===something", then those should be rejected?  If so, one thing I just learned in JavaScript is the search method (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search)  where "something something".search(/==+?/g) will return -1, but "something==something".search(/==+?/g) will return 9.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Yes! That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks! If the question is fine and shouldn't be deleted you should have posted it as an answer so that I can mark it as solved. Will reference you in the issue or pull request that fixes this in WikiJs.